# why is my method returning wrong results

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a test:

```
    public void testGetUniqueResults(){
APRecord p1 = new APRecord();
p1.settId("l1");
APRecord p2 = new APRecord();
p2.setId("l2");
APRecord p3 = new APRecord();
p3.setId("l1");
APRecord p4 = new APRecord();
p4.setId("l4");
List< APRecord > listPatch = new ArrayList< APRecord >();
listPatch.add(p1);
listPatch.add(p2);
listPatch.add(p3);
listPatch.add(p4);

List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
recs.addAll(listPatch);
unique(recs);
System.out.println("records" + recs); //return all the 4 results whereas it should return 3



}
```

and a method:

```
    public List<ARecord> unique(List<Record> list) {
    System.out.println(list);

    HashMap<String, ARecord > uniqueRecs = new HashMap<String, ARecord >();

    for(ARecord records:list){
        if(!uniqueRecs.containsKey(records.getId())){
            uniqueRecs.put(records.getId(), records);
        }
    }
    List< ARecord > finalRecs = new ArrayList< ARecord>(uniqueRecs.values());
    for(ARecord record:finalRecs){
        System.out.println("records final in method "+record);
    }


    return finalRecs; //returns correct result
}
```

My finalRecs in method unique returns the expected results but when I pass recs to my unique list, it returns all my results whereas I'm expecting three results but I get all four even though my method unique returns 3 results. Where am I doing wrong? any help appreciated.

Comment: The answer has already been given by Tim. I just want to point out that there is no need to create new lists (recs and finalRecs), you could just keep using the existing ones. Also strictly speaking your test isn't a test as it doesn't assert anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing 4 results is that you never use the return value from your method `unique()`.  And you also do not operate on the input `List` which you pass in, so the effort in your method is currently for naught.  Here is where your code currently stands:

```
List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
recs.addAll(listPatch);
unique(recs);           // you never use the return value!
```

Replace this code with the following and all should be good:

```
List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
recs.addAll(listPatch);
recs = unique(recs);    // you should be fine now
```

Comment: It also looks like the OP should just be using a `Set`.

Comment: @chrylis Agreed.  Actually, the OP contains a ton of wasteful and repetitive code.  But I just wanted to point out the bigger problem here.

Comment: @chylis Set actually doesn't work for what my service is trying to do.